# Cypress fails to visit localhost

Tags: docker, cypress

I am new to Cypress, I am trying to run a simple test on a docker container but I get this error:

```
cy.visit() failed trying to load:

http://bp.localhost:84/

We attempted to make an http request to this URL but the request failed without a response.

We received this error at the network level:

  > Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND bp.localhost

Common situations why this would fail:
  - you don't have internet access
  - you forgot to run / boot your web server
  - your web server isn't accessible
  - you have weird network configuration settings on your computer
```

But my container is running and I can access to the test website from my browser

[image]

I have been looking around for a solution, but most of the ones I've found are related to Cypress being inside the same docker image.

I have installed it locally with npm install since I cannot modify the image itself.

How do I access the above URL then?

Comment: Can you give a few more details? Are you accessing the website in your browser locally also via http://bp.localhost:84/? For a Docker container running locally on localhost, shouldn't it be http://localhost:84/ rather than http://bp.localhost:84/?

Comment: Yes, I am accessing the website through bp.localhost:84, I have this in my hosts file:

# Added by Docker Desktop
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
# End of section
127.0.0.1 bp.localhost

Comment: Did you ever figure out the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. Add a `baseUrl` to the `cypress.config.ts`
2. Update my `hosts` file

**cypress.config.ts**

```
import { defineConfig } from "cypress";

export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    baseUrl: 'bp.localhost:84',
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // implement node event listeners here
    },
  },
});
```

**/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1    bp.localhost:84
```

I’m on MacOS, so if you’re on Windows, then of course your hosts file will be in a different location

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).